# Purchased an 'new' iPhone 8 from a 3rd party; when I tried to activate it, Sprint advised it was already activated/under contract

Tags: iphone

The iPhone 8 arrived still 'new' in its original packaging, however I was informed by Sprint that the phone had already been activated & was under contract for the next 18 months. I filed a claim/dispute through Paypal who investigated and, fortunately, refunded my money. However, now I have a brand new phone that I cannot activate for myself; what can I do??

Comment: who is paying Sprint for the contract

Comment: Hi. I'm guessing no one is; I bought the phone from some guy on eBay & it came still factory-sealed. I called Sprint to add it to my current Sprint account & when I gave her the IMEI #, the CSR advised me that the phone had already been activated-on someone else's acct-and already had a phone number assigned to it. I asked her how that might have happened & she said that Sprint was having a special on the iPhone 8 (get one for $8/mo.) & that 'probably someone who didn't care about their credit' got the phone that way-then sold it to me for cash & will never pay for the phone/serv. Suggestions?

Comment: so is the phone unlocked ? will Sprint now activate you as user and make you pay the contract? Meanwhile report the guy to ebay so he will newer sell anything there anymore.

Comment: I actually never took the phone out of the box. After Sprint told me that it was under contract (for the next 18 months) they said I could not activate it for myself. I did leave negative feedback on eBay (said he was fraudulent seller) and I also filed(and won) a dispute with PayPal and they refunded me all the $ I paid, thankfully. What do you think I should do now? I have a brand new phone in the box & it seems like I can't do anything with it.

Comment: Sorry if I did not answer your question; I am brand new to this site & have very limited knowledge about locked/unlocked cell phones. I would assume that Sprint will (likely already has) shut the phone's service off, but if that's the case, I don't know what happens after that. I would call Sprint again to ask but they are SO incompetent these days; they keep you on the phone for 3 hours for the simplest issue and they regularly bait-and-switch with products & services (at least that's been my experience over the last couple years and I've been with them since 1998).